# HDMI active switch, no switching delay

Tags: hdmi

I've been trying to connect 3 HDMI sources to one endpoint. When using analog muxes it takes about a second for the devices currently connected together to reinitialise communication after switch. Unfortunately it's too much for my design. Is there any other way? I'm trying to avoid FPGA, as the deadline for the project approaches. For now I was unable to find anything resembling active HDMI switch. Ideal would be some ice with buffer inside and switchable input source.

Comment: Do you need AACS copy protection to be supported?

Comment: What are your 'devices' ? I am no expert but all HDMI monitors I have ever used take a short time to synchronise.

Comment: Are the sources synchronized to each other to begin with? If not, you'll need frame buffers to time-align them, which is not a simple design.

Comment: They are not synchronized, i found http://www.analog.com/en/products/adv7630.html
which gives me what i want ( i think) Do you have any opinions on this chip?
AACS copy protection is not needed, as sources are cameras and target is single monitor